# How to encrypt text on a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, encryption

:)
I want to create a webpage with encrypted text on it which a C# program can decrypt. Could I do this?
I have a WebBrowser on a C# form which loads a page and displays a serial code. I don't want anyone to find out this code, therefore that's why I thought about encrypting it. Maybe there's a better way to do this?
Thanks! :)

Comment: why are you publishing a code online that you don't want anyone to see?

Comment: Encrypt it with 2ROT13: http://www.pruefziffernberechnung.de/Originaldokumente/2rot13.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean serial code literally, as in a key for some software that should only be viewable by the intended recipient? If this is the case then kudos for putting more thought and effort in, many places send these around unencrypted.

The answer really is that you need SSL. You need the end-user to be able to read it, so they must have all the information necessary to decrypt it. This means you need an encryption method which still works if someone is listening in (if no one is listening in, why are you encrypting it?), so you must either pre-exchange keys or some secret, use public key cryptography, or use something like D-H key exchange.

The only option that's secure if a third party could make changes to your communications as well as eavesdrop on them is if there is some authentication outside the system, or some transitive trust mechanism. Security certificates for SSL perform this exact function.

You could do this all yourself, but you would be reinventing a whole stack of technologies that's present in every web browser. Buy a cert, send the page over SSL.

Comment: good point, I hadn't thought that that's what was meant; +1 for you and my answer deleted

Comment: I thought I had completely misinterpreted the question after reading your answer, I was going to delete mine and let yours stand! @Joey, the solution depends largely on what you're trying to achieve here. Is the web browser component necessary, or just how you are tackling the problem? If yes see above, if no read on: If you are purely trying to get some encrypted text from a server to a C# program, please amend your question to be clearer and I will write a new answer ;) (or Andras can undelete his!)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! Had to type the question quickly. ;)  
That's exactly what I meant, so thanks ZoFreX! I'll buy a SSL cert.